# "th:if" problems while sending url-coded information

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm starting coding with thymeleaf and also i'm not very advanced on HTML.
I'm setting up a webApp which manages a db. This has to add and modify three different entities.

The thing is that I want to make only one template for those three different forms. I think is not necessary to triplicate files since I can use some th:if tags. (I have to say that I'm an student and the notes the teacher gave us about thymeleaf are quite poor)

I have an index.html in which there is only 3 links redirecting to "../nuevo/P" ; "../nuevo/M" ; "../nuevo/E" .

Going into the controller, i have something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/nuevo/{dependencia}")
public String enlace(@PathVariable(value="dependencia") char dependencia , Model model) {

    return "nuevoRegistro"; 
}
```

This goes into "nuevoRegistro" template...

```
<p th:text="'Nuevo '+ ${dependencia}" />
<div th:if="${dependencia == 'E'}">
    <form action="/nuevo/E" method="post">
        <p>
            <b>Modelo:</b> <input type='text' name='modelo' />
        </p>

        <p>
            <b>Ano:</b> <input type='text' name='ano' />
        </p>
             /* some more fields 
                   .
                   .
                   .  */

        <input type='submit' value='Enviar' />
    </form>
</div>
<div th:if="${depencencia == 'M'}">
    <p>M</p>
</div>
<div th:if="${depencencia.equals('P')}"> //I was only trying new things here
    <p>P</p>
</div>
```

As far as I know, th:if does generate code if expression results true but im actually really confused with this ${}, @{} ... tags and dont know very well how to use them as you can see.

I'm getting this error once i click any of the index links:

> An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path
>   resource [templates/nuevoRegistro.html]")
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
>   during template parsing (template: "class path resource
>   [templates/nuevoRegistro.html]")

and I suppose that the problem should be in the "th:if" statement.
What is wrong? 
If I change the th:if statements maybe sometimes i get the "Nuevo + ${dependencia}" but im never getting the div I need.

Hope you can help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: whoops i forgot to write the error im getting

Comment: The thymeleaf docs and examples are actually pretty good. Just take a look.